# confused about system call logic

Tags: c, operating-system

```
if(system("mkdir junk 2>/dev/null ") != 0);
```

In the code above, I understand that a new directory called junk is being created and that the standard error is being redirected to the null device. My question is, will the line of code return non-zero values as long as the directory junk exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the MAN page.

> The return value of system() is one of the following:

```
   *  If command is NULL, then a nonzero value if a shell is available,
      or 0 if no shell is available.

   *  If a child process could not be created, or its status could not
      be retrieved, the return value is -1.

   *  If a shell could not be executed in the child process, then the
      return value is as though the child shell terminated by calling
      _exit(2) with the status 127.

   *  If all system calls succeed, then the return value is the
      termination status of the child shell used to execute command.
      (The termination status of a shell is the termination status of
      the last command it executes.)
```

Thus you could get a zero value of no shell is available. That means the command might never execute and you could get a zero.

The way to do this is the make a system call to create the directory.

Comment: So to clarify, system("mkdir junk 2>/dev/null "); returns non-zero. And for a system call to be 0, it would be:  system("rmdir junk");?

Comment: It could return a whole range of values, as described above.

Comment: If that's the case, would this code then be an infinite loop?
 while(system("mkdir junk 2>/dev/null ") != 0);

Comment: I don't see a loop there.